# Ajax get call won't pass parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor

I using Razor Page with net.core.Cant pass parameter via ajax call. Call without any parameter work great but when i wanna add some call wont do anything.

Already tried:

```
var userId = someid;
$.ajax({
                url: '?handler=UserInformation',           
                data: userId ,
            }).done(function (result) {
                //rest of code
            })          
}
```

Was trying to add dataType, contentType, method,type anyone want run my function. changing data to

```
data:{userId:userId}
```

still doesn't work.

Using just ajax without parameter will fire my function.

```
 $.ajax({
           url: '?handler=UserInformation',           
        }).done(function (result) {
                //rest of code
        })          
}

public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetUserInformation()
{}
```

But when I add a parameter

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetUserInformation(string userId)
{
    //return some data
}
```

When I paste url to website with ?handler=UserInformation&userId=grege function is fire. But when i trying hardcode it into url still wont fire.

```
url: '?handler=UserInformation&userId=grege',
```

Why my ajax call wont fire function. I think i bad pass parameter but trying already much way.

Comment: You need to use `'/grege?handler=UserInformation'`

Comment: is still not working and cant add '/' because is on same pagemodel  view from where i call it

Comment: Ah i solved the problem. I was just mistake with onclick function. I was using onclick="informationAboutUser(@user.Id)" but have to add '' inside function onclick="informationAboutUser('@user.Id')"...